# Optimize ruby on rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app have in a few pages a map with many markers.

So in my controller I send a hash with the coordinates to the view.

```
setups = current_user.setups
coordinates_hash = Hash.new { |hsh, key| hsh[key] = {} }
setups.each do |i|
  if i.address.lat != nil && i.address.long != nil
    lat = i.address.lat
    long = i.address.long
    coordinates_hash[i.setup_id].store 'lat', lat
    coordinates_hash[i.setup_id].store 'long', long
  end
end
```

So in the view I receive this hash

```
var coordenadas = <%= raw(@coordinates_hash.to_json) %>;
```

How I can optimize this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On following  @sergio and [Guide Ruby on Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)  You could change your code like

```
coordinates_hash = Hash.new { |hsh, key| hsh[key] = {} }

setups = current_user.setups.includes(:address)

setups.each do |i|
  if i.address.lat.present?  && i.address.long.present?
    coordinates_hash[i.setup_id].store 'lat', i.address.lat
    coordinates_hash[i.setup_id].store 'long',  i.address.long
  end
end
```

click here to know more about  [ActiveRecord Eager Loading Associations Includes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Answer (score -2):

## Update

*In my original Answer, I completely missed that `Address` and `Setup` are different relations. So here's an up to date answer!*

The main problem, the "N+1 Query" can be solved in two ways:

### 1) Eager load all addresses

```
setups = current_user.setups.includes(:addresses)
```

This will load all adresses for all setups. However, we only need the ones with a `lat` and a `long`.

### 2) Join Query

First, add the following line to your `User` model:

```
has_many :addresses, through: :setups
```

this allows you to do this:

```
current_user.addresses.where('lat is not null and long is not null')
```

Which results in a single query.

Final Result:

```
@coordinates = {}

addresses = current_user.addresses
          .where('lat is not null and long is not null')
          .select(:lat, :long)

addresses.each do |address|
  @coordinates[address.setup_id] = address.slice(:lat, :long)
end
```

Comment: You missed the N+1 query.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Dang, I did!